# jScrollPane dynamic width not working

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am unable to successfully achieve dynamic width resizing for %age defined scroll-pane divs upon window resize.  The solution provided on the jScrollPane demo site doesn't work for me either and I have tested in FF, Chrome and Safari. Very strange...

Demo: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_width.html

Does this demo work for you? If anyone has a solution it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - the demo is also broken for me... This must have happened in some updates I implemented over the weekend. Please try a slightly older version of jScrollPane until I fix this (old versions are available from the github site: https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/archives/master - I'm pretty sure beta 9 didn't have this problem)

Comment: This is now fixed in the plugin and the demo will work (make sure you clear your cache): http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_width.html